# I'm changing my dog's diet, is this ok?

Tags: dogs, diet

I recently changed my dog's diet. He is a 2 years old labrador (weights 90lbs), and he has been eating Purina Dog Chow for that length of time. 3 months ago I changed his diet for good:

- cooked beef (cattle) (40%)
- oats (55%)
- carrots (5%)
- 1 raw egg
- 2 spoons of oil

2.2 lbs daily (divided into 2 meals). Do you think it is enough nutritionwise? Thanks!

Comment: When in doubt about health, always seek a professional. You might get a very good answer here, but it cannot replace a pet health professional, if available.

Comment: @Flummox I already did, the Veterinarian suggested that diet, but I wanted a second opinion from someone that might have tried a similar diet for a long time.

Comment: This was posted a while ago, but you need to be sure you are feeding a balanced diet..

Answer (score 2):

I have been feeding my dog (60 pound Siberian) raw meats since she was a little pup. Feeding your dog anything other than kibble is pretty much always an improvement as dog kibble is notoriously bad for dogs, some of them even causing cancer. I am not an expert, but have done my fare share of research on the topics. Overall, dogs have very different requirements than us humans, as they have a higher acidity to their stomach acids. So, where we cannot eat raw meat, it is perfectly safe for them, but you must be careful while handling it. At the end of the day, the only true difference between raw and cooked meats is that in cooking the meat some of the nutrients are cooked out. Cooked meats are still a world of a difference better than kibble. I'd say good on you for switching things up for your dog, whatever the reasons were, I hope your dog is healthy and happy.

You should see your dogs coat get softer with the higher quality food, and if you are feeding your dog the correct number of calories they will have a healthy physique (ie: when dogs are standing on all 4's they should have an "hourglass figure" between their hind legs, down to their belly, then back up over their ribs towards their front shoulders. You should not be able to see our easily count their ribs, this tells you they are not getting enough food. If their belly is growing, they are eating too much).

Again, I am not a professional, my vet was able to provide me with the correct number of calories for my dog to eat on a daily basis based on our exercise levels and age.

Comment: Raw feeding is way better than kibble yes, but it has to be done right, if you dont have a balanced raw diet, it wont be beneficial for your dog...the key is to balance the raw diet.. if you cant balance your dogs raw diet, a high quality balanced kibble is better off..